# What does Restorative Mist do?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

Restorative Mist is, apparently, the MEC version of a medkit. How does it compare to medkits, though? How many uses do you get? What's the radius? How many hitpoints are healed per use?

Comment: At the level at which you first get it, you get one use per mission and it has a radius of three squares. Can't answer the rest because my MEC was killed by a Mectoid before she got a chance to use it!

Answer (score 8):

It is the same health restoration as using a medkit (4 or 6 depending on Foundry project), but it applies to every soldier in it's 3 tile range (including the MEC that uses the skill).  You cannot use it to revive/stabilize soldiers who are bleeding out.

When you first get it you may use it once per mission, if you pick up Expanded Storage as your Captain promotion you get an additional use.

Here is a screenshot of Restorative Mist in action.  [image: Restorative Mist]
It's a little hard to see the grid, but the lone soldier at the top of the stack on the left is 3 squares away in a straight line from the MEC using Mist.

Comment: Does it benefit from the Improved Medkit foundry improvement?

Comment: I would assume so, but I'll let you know when my MEC gets out of the infirmary.

Comment: How does the 3-tile range work on the 2d grid?

Comment: @kotekzot it's a circle that has a diameter of 3 tiles if aligned with the grid. Before you activate the ability you can see which characters it will and will not affect, as with grenades etc.

Comment: I understand how the game handles radii, I'm asking what tiles around the users this particular ability will affect.

Comment: @Flyto With Improved Medikit, it heals 6 hp per soldier.  I haven't ever used it without IM, but I'd have to guess that it'd be 4.